# How to create 2 servers in AWS, one DC and another member of DC and make the relation last after IPs change

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-web-services

I am planning to build a sharepoint development farm on AWS.
I know how to do this, but I need a minimum of 2 servers

Server 1: Domain Controller, W2012R2, DC Role 1gb of RAM
Server 2: Sql Server + Sharepoint, W2013R2, 8GB of RAM

My questions is how can I join the server 2 to domain on server 1 on AWS?

2nd. Question:  Because this is a labo environment, I want to be able to stop the servers to avoid costs.

When I restart them again, server 2 should be joined to the domain still eve if server IPs change.

Is this possible>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a VPC and make the domain on the private network (thus, assign fixed, private IPs).

Comment: could you please elaborate more? I am not a network expert :)

Comment: @EstebanV If you don't know how to do that, then this is not the site for you.  We expect users to understand the basics of whath they're doing.  That said, [there is documentation on how to create a Virtual Private Cloud over at Amazon's VPC page](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/).